# "error": "E_VALIDATION", "status": 400 node.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, http-status-code-400, validationerror

I am trying to save time entered by user in my database. But I am getting `E_VALIDATION` error `400`. This is how I am trying to save it in my database

```
StopSchedule.create( timeObj ,function stopScheduleCreate (err,timeObj)
    {
        if(err){ 
            return next(err);
        }
        else
        {
            res.json(timeObj);
        }
    });
```

I have used `console.log()` to check the value of `timeObj` it shows

`{ stopId: '1', routeId: '1', arivalTime: '12:02:10' }`

This is exactly how I need it. If I send it with empty time filed it is saved successfully. Please guide me to solve this problem.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE:
The model is as follows

```
module.exports = {
    schema      :true,
    tableName   :'stopschedule',
    connection  :'mysql-adapter',
    migrate     :'safe',
    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false,


    attributes: {

        stopId: {
            type: 'int',
        },

        routeId:{
            type: 'int',
        },

        arivalTime: {
            type:'time',
        },
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data format is wrong. What if you try with :

```
{ stopId: '1', routeId: '1' }
```

Can you give you model cofiguration ?

Comment: I have provided the model in the question

Comment: And If try with `{ stopId: '1', routeId: '1' }` The `stopId` and `routeId` are successfully saved

Comment: I think you should try a datetime in your model. And have availTime = new Date ()

Comment: I do not want to save date in my table.
Just time is needed for my work

Comment: It appears, according to the Sails doc, that Time type does not exist.
http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Attributes.html
You can store a String, or a Datetime object and get access to all of its methods.

Comment: Thanks
I will check which one will be better